# Calculating fields (multiple) with different conditions for each field using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I have a population dataset where I want to reclassify the age groups and include gender. I have the field "gender", 1 for men and 2 for women, and the field "age". One row for each person in the dataset.

I want 5-year age groups based on gender: Men 0-4 years (M_0_4), men 5-9 (M_0_9)...up to M95_99 and W_0_4, W_5_9 and so on. I can do this manually for each field with this code:

```
M_0_4=
    Reclass(!gender!, !age!)

    #codeblock:
    def Reclass(gender, age):
       if (gender = 1 and age >= 0 and age <= 4):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Is there anyway to do this for all fields using calculate field (multiple) in one go? Each field would need a different condition. I have tried making a separate expression for each field and then just copying the codeblock for each and changing the expression name and conditions without luck, e.g:

```
#expressions:
M_0_4=
  m_0_4(!gender!, !age!)
M_5_9=
  m_5_9(!gender!, !age!)

#codeblock:
def m_0_4(gender, age):
   if (gender = 1 and age >= 0 and age <= 4):
        return 1
   else:
        return 0

def m_5_9(gender, age):
   if (gender = 1 and age >= 5 and age <= 9):
       return 1
   else:
       return 0
```

Comment: You could make a model and duplicate your field calculate tool, one for each field and run the model. This would be like you running them in sequence. To run in parallel would require an update cursor and python scripting.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit confused on what you want. The way I would do this is one new field say called 'age_bin' with values like M_0_4 or F_35_40 for each row.

But you keep mentioning multiple fields and the your code is returning 1 or 0 which makes me think you want a field per gender/age combo with a 1 or 0 denoting whether or not the row is in that bin. I can't understand why you would do it that way personally as it will make your attribute table way larger and harder to interpret than a single column with binned data.

I would use this little bit of code to create the strings to represent the bins in a single field:

```
def binning(!age!,!gender!):
    rounded = int(5 * round(float(age)/5))
    if rounded > age:
        return gender + "_" + str(rounded-5) + "_"+ str(rounded-1)
    else:
        return gender + "_" + str(rounded) + "_"+ str(rounded+4)
```

If age = 12 the rounded value is 10. 10 is less than 12 so age must be in bin M_10_14.

If age = 28 the rounded value is 30. 30 is greater than 29 so age must be in bin M_25_29

If age = 45 the rounded value is 45. 45 is not less than 45 so the age must be in bin M_45_49.

I haven't tested it in Arc, but it works in Python 3 Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd do it that way but the data has to be structured this way because it going into a model afterwards. Changing the structure would require changing the model as well.